# Redirect subdomain homepage to domain specific page in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, redirect, wp-redirect

I have a wordpress multisite with one site to **domain.com** and another to **materials.domain.com**

At the domain site I have a page **domain.com/materials**

I'd like to redirect the **materials.domain.com** homepage to the **domain.com/materials**

I'm using a child theme to my subdomain instalation and trying the following on functions.php

```
wp_redirect(home_url('https://domain.com/materials'),301);
exit;
```

Now when I access the **materials.domain.com** the showed url is **https://materials.domain.com/https://domain.com/materials/**

What i'm doing wrong? How can I achieve the correct redirection?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for (I have added what I think is the answer). Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the redirect within the CPanel of wherever your website is being hosted from? I manage all of my redirects there, rather than from within my functions.php. There's a really simple guide on doing that [here](https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/cpanel/cpanel-domain-features/redirects).

Or is there a specific reason that you would like the redirect to be within the functions.php?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se] and thanks for your efforts in contributing to our pool of answers. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
wp_redirect(home_url('https://domain.com/materials'),301);
```

`home_url` adds the home URL to the start of the link. In your case you get something as if you had gone:

```
$out = "https://materials.domain.com/" . "https://domain.com/materials/";
```

Instead, try this:

```
wp_redirect('https://domain.com/materials',301);
exit;
```

that will send the user to the link without the part you do not want.